# how to display laravel data in the form of text field values,

Tags: laravel-5

i am trying to display the laravel mmysql data in text field values, i am displaying upto table format, but i also need to update that value of the filed, like text filed values,
here is my code to display data in table format

```
<table border=1 align=center>

<thead>
<tr>
<td><h4>Name</h4></td>
<td><h4>Phoneno</h4></td>
<td><h4>Checkpost</h4></td>
<td><h4>Usertype</h4></td>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
@foreach($profile as $user) 
<tr>
<td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->phoneno }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->checkpost }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->usertype }}</td>
</tr> 
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
@endsection
```

Comment: you want to display datas of `user` in `input` fields rather than in plain `table` rows?

Comment: ya, i want to display the data in the form of input fields.

Comment: `<td><input type="text" value="{{$user-name}}"</td>` do this for other columns as well if this is what you are trying to do